# ReferenceError on a Function

Tags: javascript, onchange

I just want a quick question regarding javascript. I saw on w3schools the onchange on select to run a function. I am still learning Javascript and jQuery so if I miss something, please tell me.

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
.....
</select>
```

Then on my external JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
.....
  console.log("TEST01");
  function myFunction() {
    console.log("TEST02");
  }
.....
});
```

When I load my page, on console, I can see TEST01 printing but when I made some changes in select, it gives me `ReferenceError myFunction is not defined`

Comment: The functions called in inline listeners must be global. `myFunction` inside `$(document).ready(...)` is not global, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Oh . That worked. Did not know that. Thank you. I am still learning both. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: `myFunction()` is declared inside another function (the `$(document).ready` handler), so it will only be available from within that function. From your HTML `onchange`, which executes in the global scope, it's invisible. You should use `$("#mySelect").change(myFunction)`.

Comment: Instead of inline listeners, you should attach the events with [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) (as you seem to use it).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inline callback, do it in jQuery way listening on the `onChange` callback with `$('#mySelect').on('change', myFunction)`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("TEST01");
  
  function myFunction() {
    console.log("TEST02");
  }
  
  $('#mySelect').on('change', myFunction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. You did go and beyond to teach me what I need. Thanks again.